# Managing links in Excel source workbooks when duplicating source files

Tags: database, vba, excel, save

I have three files:

Activefile - where my code is stored and run

Databasefile - where my raw data is housed (has lots of protection)

Copyofdatabasefile - is a copy without the protection

I have a macro that runs in *activefile* to update a *databasefile* excel file, later in the macro, I then use the saveas method on the *databasefile* to make a *copyofdatabasefile* file, I remove some functionality to allow people to access the data easily without going through some of the checks on the main *databasefile*.

When saving the *copyofdatabasefile*, the links in my active file are updated to look at the new *copyofdatabasefile* file. I don't want this to happen.

How can I adjust my excel links/code to ensure that the links in my file aren't transferred across to the *copyofdatabasefile*?

Saveas macro options are currently:

```
Databasefile.SaveAs filename:="\\somelocation\copyofdatabasefile.xlsx", FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Workbook.SaveCopyAs Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-savecopyas-method-excel) should work.

**If your original file is xlsx use**

```
Databasefile.SaveCopyAs Filename:="\\somelocation\copyofdatabasefile.xlsx"
```

Note that it saves in the same FileFormat as the original file only!

---

**If your original file is xlsm use**

If you need to change the file format (eg from `xlsm` to `xlsx`) you need to save as copy in the original file format first, then reopen that copy with `Workbooks.Open()` and then use `.SaveAs` to change the FileFormat.

```
Databasefile.SaveCopyAs Filename:="\\somelocation\copyofdatabasefile.xlsm" 'if original file was xlsm

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("\\somelocation\copyofdatabasefile.xlsm")
wb.SaveAs filename:="\\somelocation\copyofdatabasefile.xlsx", FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False
wb.Close False
Kill "\\somelocation\copyofdatabasefile.xlsm" 'delete old format
```